# What is the format of mol2vec featurize?

Tags: computational-chemistry

When I use the featurize command in [mol2vec](https://opensourcelibs.com/lib/mol2vec), I get a .csv file as an output with about 300 columns. But these columns are simply labelled by their number. What feature does each column represent?

Reference:  Jaeger, S.; Fulle, S.; Turk S. *Mol2vec: Unsupervised Machine Learning Approach with Chemical Intuition* in *J. Chem. Inf. Model.* **2018**, *58*, 1, 27–35; [doi 10.1021/acs.jcim.7b00616](https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.jcim.7b00616).

Comment: For future reference: there was to little information to understand the question right from the get-go, so I added what *looks* like the program your question is about (I don't know it).  Perhaps a more suitable audience is [mattermodelling](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/) than chemistry.se.

Answer (score 4):

To quote from *a* documentation of the program [here](https://opensourcelibs.com/lib/mol2vec) (still *assuming only* it were the one of the question):

> **Subcommand 'featurize'**
>
> Featurizes new samples using pre-trained Mol2vec model. It saves the result in CSV file with columns for molecule identifiers, canonical SMILES (generated during featurization) and all potential SD fields from input SDF file and finally followed by mol2vec-{0 to n-1} where n is dimensionality of embeddings in the model.
>
> **Example:**
>
> To featurize new samples using pre-trained embeddings and using vector trained on uncommon samples to represent new substructures: `mol2vec featurize -i new.smi -o new.csv -m model.pkl -r 1 --uncommon UNK`
>
> For more detail on individual subcommand run: `mol2vec $sub-command --help`